# Почему ошибка в PHP Quickstart (Drive REST API)

Tags: php, api, google-drive

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(list) unknown parameter: 'pageSize'' in /var/www/test0604/google_test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test0604/google_test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Drive.php(1872): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#1 /var/www/test0604/google_test/quickstart.php(81): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->listFiles(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/test0604/google_test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 151
```

Все дела по инструкции как тут [https://developers.google.com/drive/...](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php#prerequisites)

Прзи запуски скрипта он выдает ошибку

Comment: Ну и вы думаете что если мы не видим ваш код - то мы его себе представим?

Comment: @u_mulder, я же говорил что все делал пр  инструкции. Код тот же что и там